# How to know what difficulty I am playing on?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I seemed to have skimmed past this when creating my vault. How can I check what difficulty I am on after creating the vault?

Comment: Let someone die and see if there is revive option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vault list will show whether a vault is in [Survival Mode](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Survival_mode_(Fallout_Shelter)) or not.

Vault 219 in the screenshot has the "S" poker chip indicating Survival Mode.

[image]

Comment: Poker chip? That looks more like an environmental hazard sign.

Answer (score -1):

As far as i'm aware there is no difficulty option in Fallout Shelter. Simply, the games difficulty slowly increases as you level up your vault dwellers and your vault.

Comment: OP is probably asking about how to check if game is [survival](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Survival_mode_(Fallout_Shelter)) or not.

Comment: Ah okay, my apologies.